# How to get correct buffer size with std::istringstream for data parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, zeromq

I am sending the message of variable size over zeromq TCP socket. In the examples http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:wuclient it was proposed to use `std::istringstream` to parse the data. The problem is, that it is not accounted for the different buffer size. I end up getting the end of the longer previous message appended to the end of the shorter one.

The simple `std::string(static_cast<char*>(request.data()), request.size());` works fine to get the whole message, but I would like to use `std::istringstream`, because I am going to pass different data types (primitive data types + std::string as the last variable), so `std::istringstream` could be a good choice for the message parsing.

So this here will put correctly the whole message into rpl variable

```
zmq::message_t request;
//  Wait for next request from client
socket_.recv (&request);
auto rpl = std::string(static_cast<char*>(request.data()), request.size());
std::cout << rpl << std::endl;
```

But this will not:

```
zmq::message_t request;
//  Wait for next request from client
socket_.recv (&request);
std::istringstream iss(static_cast<char*>(request.data()));
std::string rpl;
iss >> rpl;
std::cout << rpl << std::endl;
```

How can I get around with it and tell `std::istringstream` what is the actual buffer size to get the proper string length?

Comment: Two things: If the data contains embedded null characters (bytes which are zero) then the initialization of the string stream will stop at that. Secondly, the `>>` operator reads *space delimited* "words".

Comment: So it gets more complex. The requests are sent from python over zeromq, so I will need to make sure, that python sends me the null terminated string. I'll check that, but I would rather leave it as it is. I will not always have influence how the request string looks like, would like to make it more robust.

Comment: With the first direct initialization of the string `rpl` that's not needed. Then the data can even be binary with embedded zeros. But it's the second thing I think is your big problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
std::stringstream iss;
iss.write(static_cast<char*>(request.data()), request.size());
```

With a read-and-write stringstream, and its `write` function, you get full control over how many bytes behind a pointer are written. Then you don't *need* to use the stringstream constructor to populate the buffer, which implicitly constructs a `std::string` from your `char*`, without a length constraint. Unless your data is null-terminated, that's not going to work properly.

(See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) for the available features of a stringstream.)

*If* you are completely limited to a `std::istringstream`, this has no output functionality so you will have to create that `string` argument explicitly (using its own length-aware constructor), as Sam has shown. Unfortunately, this will copy your entire buffer one extra time. I find it hard to believe that using a `std::istringstream` is worth that.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed :) I was blindly following the example from zeromq and was dealing with `std::istringstream`, I will rather use `std::stringstream` and use `write`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Exactly. That's what it is about!

Answer (score 0):

Construct your `std::istringstream` explicitly using a `std::string`.

```
std::istringstream iss{std::string{
    static_cast<char*>(request.data()), request.size())
}};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this requires copying the data once more than is strictly necessary.

Comment: You have to trade something in, when you don't have the luxury of using a `std::stringstream`, and wish to limit yourself with a `std::istringstream`, as asked.

Comment: Oh, I'll give you that - honestly I hadn't even noticed that a `istringstream` was used in the question. That being said, the OP hasn't presented a good reason for such a constraint (and I can't think of one in general). I've expanded my answer accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Unless the string itself is expected to be fairly chunky, the extra copy won't be much of a factor. But that does raise an interesting question: if a `std::istringstream` had a constructor from a `std::string &&`, it would be possible to use move semantics to avoid the redundant copy.

Comment: Indeed! In general I find stringstream's buffer access to be lacking. You can't even move the buffer out of it later. I've written a few variants on a sort of "moveable" stringstream as a consequence.

Comment: That's how easy it was! Thank you :) But I select the post from Lightness Races in Orbit as the accepted answer as it is more complete. I learned something new about `std::istringstream` and `std::stringstream`, thanks to both of you!

Comment: Copies Race In Stringstreams

Comment: Thanks guys for additional insight in the comments here! I appreciate it. And I see the point of Sam, his answer is directly related to the question to get the proper buffer size with `std::istringstream`, but I selected the other answer as it gives more insight to this case.